# Typescript: Given a table of functions, create a function that takes the key of the table and the second parameter to the function in the table

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Trying to write a simple store for state.

I have a base state:

```
const state = {
    health: 100,
    maxHealth: 100,
};
type State = typeof state;
```

And I have a set of mutations

```
const mutations = {
    setHealth: (state: State, payload: { newHealth: number }) => {
        state.health = payload.newHealth;
    },

    setMaxHealth: (state: State, payload: { newMaxHealth: number }) => {
        state.maxHealth = payload.newMaxHealth;
    },
} as const;
type Mutations = typeof mutations;
```

What I am trying to do is create function that can take the key of the mutation as it's first argument, and the payload of the mutation as its second argument.

I currently have, the first parameter is typed correctly, but the second argument to `mutations[mutation]` errors with `type Parameters<Mutations[M]>[1] is not assignable to parameter of type '{ newHealth: number; } & { newMaxHealth: number; }'.`

```
const commit = <M extends keyof Mutations>(mutation: M, payload: Parameters<Mutations[M]>[1]) => {
    mutations[mutation](state, payload);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mutations[mutation]` evaluates to `(state: State, payload: { newHealth: number } & { newMaxHealth: number }) => void` and your `payload` variable evaluates to `{ newHealth: number; } | { newMaxHealth: number; }` when TS wants it to be `{ newHealth: number; } & { newMaxHealth: number; }`

This makes sense because TS wants to treat `mutations[mutation]` as ALL the possible functions at once. From TS' perspective, in order for `payload` to be valid as a parameter to `mutations[mutation]` (setHealth | setMaxHealth), it must match ALL the possible function definitions simultaneously.

The way I would handle this is by asserting that `mutations[mutation]` matches our `payload` type:

```
interface State {
    health: number;
    maxHealth: number;
}

const mutations = {
    setHealth: (state: State, { newHealth }: { newHealth: number }) => {
        state.health = newHealth;
    },

    setMaxHealth: (state: State, { newMaxHealth }: { newMaxHealth: number }) => {
        state.maxHealth = newMaxHealth;
    },
};

type Mutations = typeof mutations;

const o = {
    state: { health: 0, maxHealth: 0 },
    commit<M extends keyof Mutations, P extends Parameters<Mutations[M]>[1]>(mutation: M, payload: P) {
        (mutations[mutation] as (state: State, payload: P) => void)(this.state, payload);
    },
};

o.commit("setHealth", { newHealth: 50 });
o.commit("setMaxHealth", { newMaxHealth: 100 });
```

(side note: using a generic `P` for the payload type means that objects with extra members will be considered valid, e.g. `o.commit("setMaxHealth", { newMaxHealth: 100, x: 1 })` will not error. If you don't want this functionality, just substitute `P` for `Parameters<Mutations[M]>[1]` in every place)

Good luck!